# Why list widget throws IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget, indexoutofboundsexception

**Problem**

I got strange crash report for my Android app which has list widget:

```java
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
    at me.gevorg.birthday.widget.ListProvider.getViewAt(ListProvider.java:96)
    at android.widget.RemoteViewsService$RemoteViewsFactoryAdapter.getViewAt(RemoteViewsService.java:164)
    at com.android.internal.widget.IRemoteViewsFactory$Stub.onTransact(IRemoteViewsFactory.java:85)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

**Code**

```java
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory  {
    private List<Contact> contactList;    
    private Context context;    
    private Intent intent;    
    private int appWidgetId;    
    private ContactListProvider provider;

    public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;    
        this.intent = intent;

        // Get widget id.
        this.appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        // Init provider.
        provider = new ContactListProvider(context);    
        this.contactList = provider.getContacts();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.contact_birthday);

        // Get contact.
        Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

        // Generate view based on contact...

        return remoteView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        this.contactList = provider.getContacts();
    }    
}

class ContactListProvider {    
    private Context context;

    public ContactListProvider(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        // Collect contacts here ...

        return Collections.sort(contacts);
    }
}
```

**Dirty Fix**

Note that list is read only and exception is thrown because of `Contact contact = contactList.get(position);` and because I didn't understand what causes issue, I added dummy check like this

```java
if (position >= contactList.size()) {
    return null;
}

// THIS LINE CAUSES EXCEPTION!!!
Contact contact = contactList.get(position);
```

**Question**

Obviously it is not fixing issue, but hiding it and I need your help to understand what causes this `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Are you overriding getCount?  Does it return contactList's size?

Comment: Yes I do - added it too.

Comment: Try running in debug mode, putting the breakpoints in crucial places seeing what `position` is, logging what `contactList.size()` is etc. That's some basic ideas anyway.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, modifying the contacts list at some point in the provider?

Comment: @Vucko problem is I don't know how to reproduce issue, I got this crash from user that is using my app.

Comment: That's quite painful then -_- Try the edge cases, deleting all the contacts for example, trying to break it yourself.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev not that I am aware of it, I removed view rendering / data collecting part and added full classes into question.

Comment: Did you find it? Facing same issue.

Comment: @korro Nope, dirty fix is what I use now